# How to retrieve video from database with forward and backward function in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

I am retrieving video from SQL Server in binary format in ASP.NET MVC using the `HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite()` method and video is playing, but forward and backward controls are not working on this

```
[HttpGet]
public EmptyResult VideoStream(int id = 3)
{
        using (DBVideoEntity db= new DBVideoEntity())
        {
            tbVideo vm = new tbVideo();
            vm = db.tbVideos.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
            HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(vm.Data);

            return new EmptyResult(); ;
        }
}
```

Comment: Will you include your HTML? Since you mentioned the video is playing but the forward and back buttons aren't working, this might be an issue with the script or plugin you are using for playing the video.

Comment: <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay="autoplay">
                        <source src="@Url.Action("VideoStream", "Home")" type="video/mp4">
                       
                         </video>

Comment: I am using this  and controls are appearing but video is not forwarding and backward on clicking them

Comment: Basically I need to play video stored in sql server in varbinary in asp.net Mvc